# Mocking a Promise that Resolves to a Reponse Object

Tags: angular, promise, jasmine

I have sections of code in my Angular component that look like the following:

```
for (const item of items) {
    const boxItems = item.boxItems;
    if (await self.hasID(boxItems)) {
        // perform some logic
    }
}
```

---

```
private async hasID(boxItems: BoxItems[]): Promise<boolean> {
    for (const item of boxItems) {
        let info = (await item.promise).json();
        // test fails here, info remains undefined
        // how to properly mock a Response object from a Promise at this point?
    }
}
```

Because I am using `.json()`, coming from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), I was curious how I would be able to mock this in my unit test?

I am currently doing this now:

```
const MockBoxItem = {
    promise: new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => resolve(myData))
};
```

Should I instead be doing something like:

```
const MockBoxItem = {
    promise: new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => resolve(
        new Response(new Body([JSON.stringify(myData)]))
    )
};
```

My unit test is failing because I suspect that the mocked data I return does not properly implement a `Response` object, therefore, does not contain the `.json()` method.

When I test this flow locally, the Response coming back looks like:

```
promise: ZoneAwarePromise
    _zone_symbol_state: true
    _zone_symbol_value: Response
        headers: ...
        ok: ...
        status: ...
        statusText: ...
        type: ...
        url: ...
        _body: myData
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
const MockBoxItem = {
    promise: new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => resolve(
       {
         json:()=>{
            return JSON.stringify(myData)
         }
       }
    )
};
```

Here's the JsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/n932pvt3/1/

Comment: This is definitely taking me in the right direction. However, this is what I currently get just from doing `item.promise`, `ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: true, __zone_symbol__value: Object{json: function () { ... }}}`. It would make sense to me that by doing `await item.promise`, I would get the value, but instead, it returns `undefined`. Any thoughts?

Comment: see my fiddle.     fix the return

Answer (score 0):

An mock of Response which contains `{"foo":"bar"}` in response body.
I think that `response.json()` have to return a promise of JSON.parsed object.

```
const MockBoxItem = {
  promise: Promise.resolve(new Response(JSON.stringify({foo:"bar"})))
}

async function asyncCall() {
  const result = await MockBoxItem.promise
  const data = await result.json()
  console.log(data) // { foo: 'bar' }
}

asyncCall()
```